# Is it possible to concatenate keras sequence instances?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `TimeSeriesGenerator` to generate sequences, and I have multiple time-series datasets that need to be kept separate while generating the sequences. Is it possible to generate multiple `Sequence` instances using `TimeSeriesGenerator` and then concatenate them?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have created two `Time Series Generators` with First Column being the `Time Stamp` and the Second Column being the `Labels`.

In order to combine 2 `Time Series Generators`, You can try something like shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[i] for i in range(50)])
targets = np.array([[i] for i in range(50)])

def generate_generator_multiple(data, targets):
    data_gen1 = TimeseriesGenerator(data, targets,
                               length=10, sampling_rate=2,
                               batch_size=2)
    
    data_gen2 = TimeseriesGenerator(data, targets,
                               length=10, sampling_rate=3,
                               batch_size=2)
    while True:
            X1i = data_gen1.next()
            X2i = data_gen2.next()
            yield [X1i[0], X1i[1]], X2i[1] #Yield the common Time Stamp and the respective Value

Comb_Gen = generate_generator_multiple(data, targets)

print(Comb_Gen)
```

Please refer this [Github Issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8130) which has more such workarounds.